# Find lines that DO NOT contain a specific character

Tags: c

So I need to open/read a file and find the number of lines that DO NOT contain the symbol `|`. However, I can't get this to work with `strchr()` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int countLOC(FILE *filename){

    int c, nlines = 0;

    filename = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (c != EOF){
        if (c == '\n' && strchr(c,'|') != NULL)
            nlines++;
        c = getc(filename);
    }

    printf("%d",nlines);
}

int main(){

    countLOC("charc.c");

    return 0;
}
```

The program crashes and I have no idea why. Initially, the code would just count all lines (except blank lines) but I need to check if each line contains a `|`.

Comment: you haven't initialized `c` before you start using/testing it. it won't have a useful value until AFTER you call `getc()` for the first time.

Comment: FWIW: `"charc.c"` is a string and not of type `FILE*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a character to `strchr()`, it takes a pointer to `char`. If you enable compiler warnings, you would have known this.

If you want to count the lines with your current code, you should read each character until a `'\n'` is found, keep a flag to know if there was one of occurance ot the searc character in the line, then if at least on character matched the search character, you count a line otherwise you don't, and reset the flag.

Also the line

```
filename = fopen(filename, "r");
```

is wrong, because `fopen()` returns a `FILE *` object, it's an I/O stream which you can use to read from the file.

You have other mistakes too, see this code. Hope you notice what where the other mistakes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int countLOC(const char *const filename)
{

    int c, nlines = 0;
    int found = 0;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to open %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            nlines += (found != 0) ? 1 : 0;
            found   = 0;
        }
        found = ((c == '|') || (found != 0));
    }
    nlines += (found != 0) ? 1 : 0;

    printf("%d", nlines);
    fclose(files);

    return nlines;
}

int main()
{

    countLOC("charc.c");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the time allocated. Will accept the answer ASAP :)

Comment: need `fclose(file)` and `printf("%d", nlines += found);` or something.

Answer (score 1):

```
int countLOC(const char *filename){
    int c, nlines = 0, hasCh = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    while(1){
        c = getc(fp);
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n'){
            if(hasCh)
                nlines++;
            if(c == EOF)
                break;
            hasCh = 0;
        } else if(!hasCh && c == '|'){
            hasCh = 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d\n",nlines);
    return nlines;
}
```